# Response body is null when status code is not 200 while making a retrofit call in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using my retrofit client when calling external api's.
I get a response code and also response body as well when status code is `200`.
For status code non `200` [ex `400`] with error object in response, it does not get and map response body whereas the external API is sending the body in case of a non 200.
Response body in that case is null.

Here is my builder

```
Retrofit.Builder builder =
    new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(objectMapper))
        .client(httpClient);

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```

When calling:

```
Call<ResponseDto> call =
    service.listSearch(listRequestDto);

try {
  Response<ResponseDto> response = call.execute();
}
```

When the call is `200`, ResponseDto is received and mapped but when it is non `200`, it is `null`.

Comment: when response code is not 200,the response is equal to 200 code response?

Answer (score -1):

As you are using `try` and `catch` block. You can get the error in catch block and then you can decide on what you need to do. In case of an error, you won't get a response, it will directly go to catch block.

So your code will look something like this

```
try {
  Response<ResponseDto> response = call.execute();
 } catch (err) {
   // Do what you want to do in case of error.
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: call.execute does not throw any exception. When the call is not 200, it will return the call with non 200, it does not throw exception. It puts the response it gets in the left hand side response. So in case the response code is 200, it maps the body but for non 200, the response.body is null. But the api is sending a body

Comment: Got it, in that case can you share the docs for the third party api ? That way, it will be helpful to figure out the way to handle non 200 response codes.

Comment: You converter only convert success reponse to `ResponseDto`